# Firebase not storing data. Project build successfully with no error in Logcat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-manifest

This is the registerUser function that I created. If you can see there I have done everything that need to Store the value into the database
getting reference and instances of firebase database along with setting value using setValue() method and passing user object of the constructor class User.
I don't know where i did go wrong. please help it would be really appreciable.
This is my Java code for Registering User and storing into the Firebase database

```
private void registerUser()
{
        String Email=nEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password=npassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String Username=nFullName.getText().toString().trim();
        String Phone=nphone.getText().toString().trim();

        if(Username.isEmpty()) {
            nFullName.setError("Name is required");
            nFullName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(Email.isEmpty()) {
            nEmail.setError("Email is required");
            nEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()){
            nEmail.setError("please provide valid email");
            nEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password.isEmpty()) {
            npassword.setError("password is required");
            npassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        if(password.length() < 6)
        {
            npassword.setError("password must be 6 chracters long");
            npassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(Phone.isEmpty()) {
            nphone.setError("Phone is required");
            nphone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String Email=nEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Username=nFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Phone=nphone.getText().toString().trim();

                    Users user=new Users(Username,Phone,Email);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(activity_register.this,"User Has been Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(activity_register.this,"Failed..... :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(activity_register.this,"Failed..... :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

also suggest me any dependency if it is required for the working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for your problem is, to use the FirebaseDatabase in another way. `Problem`: You are calling the "getReference" method and initialize it with the String value: "Users".

Instead of:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                    .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase var1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference userRef = var1.getReference().child("Users");
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();  
userRef = userRef.child(auth.getCurrentUser()).getUid());
userRef.setValue("your string").addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<Void>() { 
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {System.out.print("Now it works!")
        }
    }
 });
```

The setValue method requires a string value (often).

> Please do not put a class like your Users class in the setValue method.

If you want to save more than one Data-String in for a user, you can just add another .child("DataStringName") behind the users root.

Example for a username and a normal name:

```
FirebaseDatabase var1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference userRef = var1.getReference().child("Users");
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();  
userRef = userRef.child(auth.getCurrentUser()).getUid());
DatabaseReference usernameRef = userRef.child("username");
DatabaseReference nameRef = userRef.child("name");
usernameRef.setValue("Username").addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<Void>() { 
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
if(task.isSuccessful())
{System.out.print("Username is uploaded!")
}
}
});
nameRef.setValue("Name").addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<Void>() { 
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
if(task.isSuccessful())
{System.out.print("Name is uploaded!")
}
}
});
```

I hope this answer helps you!

Best Regards!

Comment: But problem is not in the second task.isSuccessful() . it is in first task.isSuccessful() where mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,password) is created is not completed for a reason

Comment: Ok i will make a new answer

Answer (score 0):

So your code for creating an account is correct.

There are several things you should task care on:

1. Have you enable the Email/Password feature in Firebase Authentication
   ([Firebase](https://firebase.com))
2. Have you followed the instructions for Android?

Please show me the log with the error response, or any response of firebase. I am sure there will be a response!